# Glob and regex matching

Tags: bash, wildcards

`Bash` has two types of pattern matching, `Glob` and `Regex`.  The general rule of usage seems to be that 1) the simpler `glob` is done to search filenames 2) `regex` is used for searching text.

`Glob` uses the metacharacters at the front, `regex` uses the metacharacters at the end of the `pattern`.

```
Glob          Regex
?(pattern)    (pattern)?
*(pattern)    (pattern)*     
+(pattern)    (pattern)+
```

I therefore have difficulty understanding how file matching with wildcards (e.g. `*.sh`).  Are wildcards something different than glob patterns?  From what I see, the search pattern `*.sh` does not include a metacharacter to match any character after `*`.

Comment: Does this help at all? [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905)

Comment: Reading the link provided, the `wildcard` is a `Shell Glob`.  Which suggests that use of `*.sh` is a different variation of Glob Matching that does not require the introduction of a metacharacter to explicitly state `any character` (as is done with regex using the `.` metacharacter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wildcard is part of a glob pattern. At their simplest `*` and `?` are wildcards that are also glob patterns. Here are some simple globs:

```
*.sh              # could match "fred.sh" and also ".sh"
matchme           # would match "matchme"
file[0-9]*.txt    # could match "file12.txt" but also "file12yz.txt"
?ile              # could match "mile" or "file" but not "smile"
```

The glob patterns you have listed in your question are *extended* glob patterns. For `bash` they are active in `[[ "$var" == {pattern} ]]` constructs but are only available for filename matching if `extglob` is enabled:

```
shopt -s extglob        # Enable extended globs (bash)
ls -d +([[:digit:]])    # List files/directories whose names are just digits
```

> From what I see, the search pattern `*.sh` does not include a metacharacter to match any character after `*`

The pattern `*.sh` uses a wildcard `*` that will match zero or more characters. Remember that globs are not Regular Expressions (ordinary or Extended), but these are equivalent:

```
Glob            RE              Description

*.sh            ^.*\.sh$        Match anything ending with the three characters ".sh"
?ile            ^.ile$          Match any single character then the text "ile"
+([[:digit:]])  ^[[:digit:]]+$  Match one or more digits (potentially any alphabet, not just 0-9)

Extended Glob   ERE             Description
@(one|two)      ^(one|two)$     Match either "one" or "two"
```

Note that an ordinary RE to match "one" or "two" would need to mark out the brackets and separator, i.e. `^\(one\|two\)$`, as they are not included. In contrast an Extended Regular Expression does include these operators, i.e. `^(one|two)$`

Comment: The `*.sh` example is still unclear to me.  Does it mean that the glob construct `*(pattern)` that does not include a pattern in parenthesis is assumed to represent `any character as pattern`?

Comment: @Veak In a glob pattern, `*` normally means "any sequence of characters", and `?` normally means "any single character". But if extended globs are enabled *and* one of those is followed by something in parentheses, its meaning shifts to "any number of these:" (`*`) or "maybe one of these:" (`?`). These secondary meanings are not part of the original design of glob patterns; they were added to extend the standard glob syntax to allow more complex (regex-like) patterns, and frankly their syntax is an ugly and inconsistent kluge.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you for your cogent answer.